How to manage Activity stack behavior in Android based on dynamic IDs?
I have one ActivityA that contains a specific ID in the intent data, one ActivityB that is open from this ActivityA, and ActivityB can also open the same ActivityA with the same ID or a different one. Seeing that opening activities this way can lead to an infinity activities in the stack, I need to manage the stack in the following way:

User opens ActivityA with ID 1, then opens ActivityB from there. So
far the stack will be like: ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB
Then, from ActivityB user opens the same ActivityA with ID 1 and the
stack will be like: ActivityA(id: 1). Note the ActivityB was just
popped from the stack.

I know I can achieve this behaviour simply using android:launchMode="singleTask". But my problem is when the user opens the ActivityA with a different ID. So here is the desired second behaviour:

User opens ActivityA with ID 1, then opens ActivityB from there. The stack will be now like: ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB
Now from ActivityB user opens the ActivityA with the ID 2 and the
stack should be like: ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB → ActivityA(id: 2). Note that instead of popping out ActivityB, it keeps in the stack and add another instance of ActivityA but now with a different ID.

Giving these two scenarios, I want two different behaviors depending on the ID from the ActivityA. And one limitation that I have is that I got no control of ActivityB, so I can't do any changes in the ActivityB.
PS: ActivityB opens ActivityA via deeplink.
Attempts
I could achieve similar behaviour using
android:documentLaunchMode="intoExisting"
android:launchMode="singleTask"

but it creates a new task every time the ActivityA is open and it would be a bad user experince.
Using taskAffinity will also create a new task and I can't afford that.
Update
My current attempt is:
AndroidManifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
                <data android:host="myhost" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>

ActivityA code
private val idsInStack = mutableSetOf<String>()


class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_a) {

    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val id = intent.data?.getQueryParameter("QUERY_ID")
        if (idsInStack.contains(id)) {
            val intent = Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java)
            intent.data = this.intent.data
            intent.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP
            )
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        id?.let { idsInStack.add(it) }

        diInjection()
    }
}

PS: ActivityB launches ActivityA via deeplink and add no flags to the intent.

You can probably accomplish want you want like this:
When ActivityA is launched, in its onCreate() it can store the ID into a static variable, that is available to all instances of ActivityA (in Kotlin you would use a property in a companion object)
When ActivityB launches ActivityA, it will always create a new instance of ActivityA.
When ActivityA is launched, the first thing it does in onCreate() (after calling super.onCreate() is to check if the id it was launched with is the same as the id stored in the static variable. If it is, it should remove all activities from the stack that are on top of the original instance of ActivityA (including itself), like this:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();

Of course, because the static variable will be there forever, you'll need to think about cleaning it up so that it doesn't break further executions of your app.
Try this out and see if it works for you.
NOTE: I don't know what should happen if ActivityA is first launched with id=5, then it launches ActivityB, which then launches ActivityA with id=3, which then launches ActivityB, which then launches ActivityA. Is this a real scenario? What should happen in this case if ActivityB launches ActivityA with id = 3? What should happen in this case if ActivityB launches ActivityA with id = 5?

Hi @davidwasser! Thanks for your idea. I thought it'd work cause of the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP but it didn't. With the finish() it finishes it self without opening the new activity, so the stack goes like this:
ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB → From B I open Activity A with ID 1, and it does nothing. Checking my current stack it stays ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB.
If I remove finish(), the Activity A opens but doesn't clear the stack as it should. And the stack stays like: ActivityA(id: 1) → ActivityB → ActivityA(id: 1).
Do you have any other suggestion?

Please edit your question and post your manifest (at least the <activity> declarations for ActivityA and ActivityB. Also post the code that you implemented to launch the ActivityA` with the flags as I suggested.

you could try calling finish() before calling startActivity() but that shouldn't make a difference. Just something to try until I get a better idea.

Please also show the code that ActivityB uses to launch ActivityA.

I just updated my question with the code I have now. ActivityB I have no control, so I can't share how it calls my ActivityA. The only thing is that ActivityB launches ActivityA via deeplink and add no flags to the intent.

Hey @davidwasser! Your solution worked. Actually calling finish() before calling startActivity() made total difference. I'll comment below with the explanation

If I close after, the system will start matching the new intent from the top, which is the current activity, and it'll do nothing because at that moment the same instance is already on top and there’s any other above to be cleaned.

However, if I close the current activity first, the system will start matching the new intent from the previous activity in the stack (in this case ActivityB), and it'll all the way down the stack till it finds the ActivityA. And at that moment, because this ActivityA instance is not on top, it’s brought up, clearing all the other activities that was above. In this case, closing the ActivityB and going back to the ActivityA.

I guess this work should be done with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP but it seems to be totally ignored.

Good to know. As you say (and as I said), it "should work". But glad you were able to resolve this. I should open a ticket for this at Google ;-)

Yeah maybe it's a good idea to open a ticket! Anyway, thanks a lot for the help in this one. Cheers!
